# 2 FloatLayouts in BoxLayout not formatting correctly

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm brand new to Kivy, and am working on the UI to get a fairly complex set of widgets to display properly. My root widget is a boxlayout(horiz), and I'm trying to get 2 floatlayouts to appear side by side. But the second floatlayout displays on the left side of the boxlayout over the first floatlayout. I've tried with and without pos_hints and size_hints at the floatlayout level, to no avail. Some base code:

```
<BoxLayout>:
    id: rootwid
    orientation: 'horizontal'

    FloatLayout:
        id: leftside
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0} (Also tried 'right' and 'top' and commenting out the line)
        #size_hint: (.5, 1)
        (Buttons & Labels here, which lay out properly within the floatlayout)

    FloatLayout:
        id: rightside
        pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y':0} (Also tried 'right' and 'top' and commenting out the line)
        #size_hint: (.5, 1)
        (Buttons & Labels here, which lay out properly within the floatlayout)
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you have a future use for the FloatLayouts, I advise that you replace  them with other types of layouts bcoz since they are float, they tend to be independent of the parent.

Try using GridLayout to house the buttons and labels and other widgets
like this;

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    GridLayout:
        cols: any
        rows: any
        # Left widgets added here

    GridLayout:
        cols: any
        rows: any
        # Right widgets added here
```

You can also nest them accordingly, for extensize insight on these run *KivyCatalog* , an inbuilt python file in kivy-examples, 
usually at ~/.local/share/kivy-examples/demo/kivycatalog/main.py for Ubuntu
for windows i think check AppData then local then share, AppData is by default hidden , dont forget that.

KivyCatalog is interative as it shows you changes in your kv code as you write it,try it.

Comment: Thanks. I will check out KivyCatalog. I was using float because I have grids in those, and then buttons and labels, and was hoping I could more easily control their sizes with the hints.